# Problema ao remover no inicio em uma lista duplamente encadeada

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Ola. Quando tento usar a função "retira" para remover o primeiro elemento da lista, aparentemente não acontece nada. Mas, logo depois de utilizar a função retira e tentar inserir um novo nó na lista, ele não insere, e na segunda vez que tento inserir, ele volta a inserir normalmente como se nada tivesse acontecido. Estou quebrando a cabeça com isso, e não consigo achar o problema do porque não remove e apresenta esse "erro" ao inserir depois de tentar remover.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct cliente{
    int senha;
    char prio;
    struct cliente *ant,*prox;
};
typedef struct cliente Cliente;

void insere_inicio(Cliente *cabeca);
void listar(Cliente *cabeca);
void libera_lista(Cliente *cabeca);
void retira(Cliente *cabeca);

int main(){

    Cliente *cabeca=(Cliente *) malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
    cabeca->prox = NULL;
    cabeca->ant = NULL;

     int q; /* Caractere para receber a opcao do usuario */
     do {
     printf("\n\nOpcoes:\
     \n1 -> para inserir no inicio o cliente;\
     \n2 -> para listar todas as senhas;\
     \n3 -> para retirar o primeiro da lista;\
     \n0 -> para sair \n:");
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%i", &q); /* Le a opcao do usuario */
     switch(q) {
     case 1: insere_inicio(cabeca); break;
     case 2: listar(cabeca); break;
     case 3: retira(cabeca); break;
     case 0: break;
     default: printf("\n\n Opcao nao valida");
     }
     fflush(stdin); /* Limpa o buffer de entrada */
     } while ((q != 0) );
     libera_lista(cabeca);
}

//função para alocar espaço de memoria e criar o nó
/**/
Cliente *aloca(){
    //tenta alocar um novo nó
    Cliente *novono=(Cliente *) malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
    if(!novono){//se não alocou, e portanto novo não existe faça
        printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{
         printf("senha: ");
         fflush(stdin);
         scanf("%i", &novono->senha); 
         printf("\nprioridade: [P] para preferencial ou [N] normal: ");
         fflush(stdin);
         scanf("%c", &novono->prio);
         fflush(stdin);
         //q = novono->prio;
         return novono;
    }
}

void insere_inicio(Cliente *cabeca) {

 Cliente *novono=aloca();
 Cliente *aux = cabeca->prox;
 cabeca->prox = novono;
 novono->prox = aux;
 novono->ant = NULL;
}

void listar(Cliente *cabeca){

    if(cabeca->prox == NULL){
        printf("\nTem nada aqui nao hein\n");
        return;
    }   
    Cliente *aux;
    aux = cabeca->prox;
    while(aux != NULL){

        printf("\n\n-------------------------------");
        printf("\nSenha: %i", aux->senha);
        printf("\nPrioridade: %c", aux->prio);
        aux=aux->prox;  
    }
}

void retira(Cliente *cabeca){

    if(cabeca->prox == NULL){
        printf("lista esta vazia");
    }else{
        Cliente *aux;
        aux = cabeca;
        cabeca = cabeca->prox;
    //  cabeca->ant = NULL; 
        free(aux);
    }
}

void libera_lista(Cliente *cabeca){
    //se a lista nao estiver vazia
    if(cabeca->prox != NULL){
        /**/
        Cliente *aux;
        aux = cabeca->prox;
        while(cabeca != NULL){
            aux = cabeca;
            cabeca = cabeca->prox;
            free(aux);

        }

        free(cabeca);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema encontra-se nessa parte:

```
void retira(Cliente *cabeca){

if(cabeca->prox == NULL){
    printf("lista esta vazia");
}else{
    Cliente *aux;
    aux = cabeca;
    cabeca = cabeca->prox;
//  cabeca->ant = NULL; 
    free(aux);
  }
}
```

Dois erros são encontrados aqui.

1º O ponteiro `aux` passa a apontar para a variavel cabeça, sendo  deveria apontar para o elemento apos a cabeça, que em tese é o primeiro elemento da lista.

2º A instrução`cabeca = cabeca->prox;` nao elimina o primeiro elemento da lista, na verdade ele faz o ponteiro `cabeca` apontar para onde já estava apontando.O correto é fazer `cabeca` apontar para o proximo do seu proximo, quem em tese seria o segundo elemento, que passará ser o primeiro

Com as devidas correções a função ficará assim:

```
 void retira(Cliente *cabeca){
     if(cabeca->prox == NULL){
       printf("lista esta vazia");
    }else{
      Cliente *aux;
      aux = cabeca->prox;
      cabeca->prox = cabeca->prox->prox;

      if(cabeca->prox != NULL){
        cabeca->prox->ant = cabeca;
      }

      aux->ant = NULL;
      aux->prox = NULL;
      free(aux);
   }
}
```